# While building jsp page i am getting this error "Expecting "jsp:param" standard action with "name" and "value" attributes"

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I had gone through various references on stackoverflow itself and tried googling it but unable to solve the issue. Below is the problem in detail, Any help would be appreciated.

```
<%@page import='java.sql.*,com.msg.DAO.*'%>
<%
String vFirstName=request.getParameter("firstName").trim();
String vLastName=request.getParameter("lastName").trim();
String vUserName=request.getParameter("userName").trim();
String vPassword=request.getParameter("password").trim();
String vHintQuestion=request.getParameter("hintQuestion").trim(); 
String vHintAnswer=request.getParameter("hintAnswer").trim();
java.util.Date javaDate=new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Date todayDate=new java.sql.Date(javaDate.getYear(),javaDate.getMonth(),javaDate.getDate());
Connection connection=DAOConnection.getConnection();
PreparedStatement preparedStatement=connection.prepareStatement("select username from member where username=?");
preparedStatement.setString(1,vUserName);
ResultSet resultSet=preparedStatement.executeQuery();
boolean b=resultSet.next();
resultSet.close();
preparedStatement.close();
if(b)
{
    connection.close();
    User user=new User();
    user.setFirstName(vFirstName);
    user.setLastName(vLastName);
    user.setUserName(vUserName);
    user.setPassword("");
    user.setHintQuestion(vHintQuestion);
    user.setHintAnswer(vHintAnswer);
    request.setAttribute("userBean",user);
    session.setAttribute("errorMessage","User exists");
    %>
<jsp:forward page='/Register.jsp'>
<%
}

preparedStatement=connection.prepareStatement("insert into member values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
preparedStatement.setString(1,vUserName);
preparedStatement.setDate(2,todayDate);
preparedStatement.setString(3,vPassword);
preparedStatement.setString(4,vFirstName);
preparedStatement.setString(5,vLastName);
preparedStatement.setString(6,vHintQuestion);
preparedStatement.setString(7,vHintAnswer);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
preparedStatement.close();
connection.close();
request.setAttribute("notificationMessage","Registration Successfull");
%>
<jsp:forward page='/Notification.jsp'>
```

Here is the stack trace

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /ProcessRegistration.jsp (line: 32, column: 0) Expecting "jsp:param" standard action with "name" and "value" attributes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer by myself. I was omitting '/' in jsp forward tag, Didn't understand why it is necessary here.
Replaced line 31, 48 by these two statements respectively

```
<jsp:forward page='/Register.jsp'/>

<jsp:forward page='/Notification.jsp'/>
```